# Match values in list of dataframes and extract in other dataframe in R

Tags: r

I'm new programming in R and I'm creating a script for a lab.

I have a list of dataframes called: "cell_type_1", "cell_type_2", ... And the inside of dataframes are like these:

`cell_type_1:`

| `ID` | `Name` | `X` | `Y` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `01` | `DAP+` | `15` | `98` |
| `01` | `DAP+` | `43` | `68` |
| `01` | `DAP+` | `34` | `05` |

`cell_type_2:`

| `ID` | `Name` | `X` | `Y` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `02` | `Cer+` | `25` | `94` |
| `02` | `Cer+` | `43` | `68` |
| `02` | `Cer+` | `77` | `22` |

And so on. But each dataframe has a variable number of rows.

I want to compare columns X and Y of all the dataframes inside the list and those that match will export their information to another new dataframe in this way:

`cell_type_n:`

| `ID` | `Name` | `X` | `Y` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `n` | `DAP+Cer+` | `43` | `68` |
| `n` | `DAP+Cer+` | `36` | `75` |

`cell_type_m:`

| `ID` | `Name` | `X` | `Y` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `m` | `DAP+Cer+Other+` | `22` | `11` |
| `m` | `DAP+Cer+Other+` | `58` | `89` |

More info about the question:

I have those dataframes with the information of segmented biological cells, then dataframes has the spatial position (X,Y) of each cell and the name of its species (Name), therefore, each dataframe will have a variable amount of cells and there will also be a variable amount of dataframes depending on how many species there are. So if the position (X,Y) of a cell with name "A+" coincides with the position (X,Y) of another one "B+" it means that this cell is "A+B+" and I want to know its position (X,Y) and the joint name ("A+B+", in this case).

To do this, the positions (X,Y) between all the dataframes must be compared and those that match are extracted to a new dataframe which, in addition to having the positions, has the names (Names column) of the species that have matched.

The number of new dataframes would be equal to all possible combinations of the dataframes (cell species) from the beginning, for example:

If we have 3 dataframes named "A+", "B+", "C+", the new dataframes would be:

```
"A+B+"
"A+C+"
"B+C+"
"A+B+C+"
```

With the respective spatial information (X,Y) and the Name column within each dataframe.

Thanks.

Comment: How many dataframes do you expect at the end?

Comment: Have you tried to use `merge`?

Comment: As many dataframes as names combinations are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **base R**. Since you're working on a list of data frames and want to compare combinations (`comb`) of them an outer `apply` is needed. Using a toy example of 4 data frames named "A" - "D" in `df_list`.

##### List of data frames

```
df_list
$A
  ID Name  X  Y
1  1 DAP+ 15 98
2  1 DAP+ 43 68
3  1 DAP+ 34  5

$B
  ID Name  X  Y
1  2 Cer+ 25 94
2  2 Cer+ 43 68
3  2 Cer+ 77 22

$C
  ID Name  X  Y
1  2 Cer+ 25 94
2  2 Cer+ 43 68
3  2 Cer+ 77 22

$D
  ID Name  X  Y
1  1 DAP+ 15 98
2  1 DAP+ 43 68
3  1 DAP+ 34  5
```

```
comb <- data.frame(combn(1:length(df_list), 2))
names(comb) <- apply(combn(names(df_list), 2), 2, paste, collapse="")

apply(comb, 2, function(x){
  res <- merge(df_list[[x[1]]], df_list[[x[2]]], c("X", "Y"))
  cbind(ID = res[,c("ID.x")], 
        Name = paste0(res$Name.x, res$Name.y), 
        res[, c("X", "Y")])})
$AB
  ID     Name  X  Y
1  1 DAP+Cer+ 43 68

$AC
  ID     Name  X  Y
1  1 DAP+Cer+ 43 68

$AD
  ID     Name  X  Y
1  1 DAP+DAP+ 15 98
2  1 DAP+DAP+ 34  5
3  1 DAP+DAP+ 43 68

$BC
  ID     Name  X  Y
1  2 Cer+Cer+ 25 94
2  2 Cer+Cer+ 43 68
3  2 Cer+Cer+ 77 22

$BD
  ID     Name  X  Y
1  2 Cer+DAP+ 43 68

$CD
  ID     Name  X  Y
1  2 Cer+DAP+ 43 68
```

##### Data

```
df_list <- list(A = structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L), Name = c("DAP+", 
"DAP+", "DAP+"), X = c(15L, 43L, 34L), Y = c(98L, 68L, 5L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), B = structure(list(ID = c(2L, 2L, 2L), Name = c("Cer+", 
"Cer+", "Cer+"), X = c(25L, 43L, 77L), Y = c(94L, 68L, 22L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), C = structure(list(ID = c(2L, 2L, 2L), Name = c("Cer+", 
"Cer+", "Cer+"), X = c(25L, 43L, 77L), Y = c(94L, 68L, 22L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), D = structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L), Name = c("DAP+", 
"DAP+", "DAP+"), X = c(15L, 43L, 34L), Y = c(98L, 68L, 5L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)))
```

Comment: There would be a size error in the dataframes.
I have those dataframes with the information of having segmented cells, then each dataframe has the spatial position (X,Y) of each cell and the name of its species (Name), therefore, each dataframe will have a variable amount of cells and there will also be a variable amount of dataframes depending on how many species there are.
So if the position (X,Y) of a cell with name "A+" coincides with the position (X,Y) of another one "B+" it means that this cell is "A+B+" and I want to know its position (X,Y) and the joint name ("A+B+", in this case).

Comment: I use these to know all possible combinations in a dataframe with a number:    
combinations <- do.call("c", lapply(seq_along(df_list$Name), 
                        function(i) combn(df_list$Name, i, 
                        FUN = list))) 

combinations <- sapply(combinations, paste, collapse="")

species <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1:length(combinations)),combinations))

So, if the input is "A","B","C" these returns: 1 | A , 2 | B, 3 | C, 4 | AB, 5 | AC, 6 | BC, 7 | ABC

Comment: Maybe with a for loop it can be done better

Comment: @AlejandroRivera Please update the question through edit cause I don't think I immediately get what you mean.

Comment: I've just done it

Comment: @AlejandroRivera That's what the answer already does. Btw, you would not have A+B+C+ because we're only comparing 2 dfs. There might be some naming adjustments necessary to fit your exact needs but to get that right i'd have to have the real data...

Comment: That's the hard part of the question, what would those adjustments be for a variable number of dfs and a variable number of rows in that dfs? Because I need to compare them all each other. I'm sorry if I'm not explaining myself well and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hm, the dfs are in the df_list, but there can be any mount, thats variable. Also, the number of rows is variable and does not matter. Every df can have any amount of differing rows. The X/Y matches are still found.

Comment: I mean that in your answer you compare two by two, but is there any way to compare them in the way I explain in the question?  i.e.: "A+B+", "A+C+", "B+C+", "A+B+C+"

Comment: And I say about the number rows because testing your code I get: 
Warning messages:
1: In df_list[[x[1]]]$X == df_list[[x[2]]]$X :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In df_list[[x[1]]]$Y == df_list[[x[2]]]$Y :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: I've changed the comparison to a merge, maybe that fits your data better. As for the comparisons, all pairwise combinations are included. You can construct higher order combinations from the results.